# 1242 Subquery returns more than 1 row

Tags: mysql, sql

I got this error, I hope you may help me. I want to show a certain item in a search.

```
SELECT p.id, p.property_rank, p.pic_numb, p.att_numb, p.confirm, p.finalized ,p.deleted, p.user_id, p.add_date, p.visit_time,p.visit_date,p.sent_numb, p.contact_numb, zip_name, zip_id, p.street, p.sp_featured, p.property_title, p.b_price_unit, p.b_price_si, p.b_price, p.b_price, p.street_no, p.field_54, 
    p.field_409, 
    ( SELECT `listing_type`.`id` 
      FROM `res_rpl_listing_types` AS `listing_type` 
      WHERE `listing_type`.`id` = (
          SELECT `listing`.`type` 
          FROM `res_rpl_listings` AS `listing` 
          WHERE `listing`.`id` = p.`listing`)
    ) AS `listing_type_id`, 
    p.listing, p.googlemap_ln, p.googlemap_lt, p.category, p.b_bedrooms, p.b_bathrooms, p.sp_openhouse, p.b_price_period, p.b_lot_area_unit, p.b_lot_area_si, p.b_lot_area, p.b_lot_area, p.b_living_area_unit, p.b_living_area_si, p.b_living_area, p.b_living_area, p.description, p.sp_hot, p.sp_forclosure 
FROM res_rpl_properties AS p 
WHERE 1 AND p.`type` = '0' AND p.`confirm` = '1' AND p.`finalized` = '1' AND p.`deleted` = '0' AND p.`category` IN(9,8,10) 
ORDER BY p.add_date DESC 
LIMIT 0 , 12
```

Comment: change  `WHERE listing_type.id = ` to `WHERE listing_type.id IN`

Comment: Which item do you want to show?

Comment: i wanna show a certain items (houses)

Comment: Now see JOIN. It's in the chapter before subqueries

Answer (score 1):

The error is telling you that your subquery (selected as `listing_type_id`) returns more than one row. To rephrase - it's returning more than one value for `listing_type_id`. You should limit the results from the subquery to just one.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

OR select just the first row of subquery

```
(SELECT `listing_type`.`id` 
 FROM `res_rpl_listing_types` AS `listing_type` 
 WHERE `listing_type`.`id` = (
       SELECT `listing`.`type` 
       FROM `res_rpl_listings` AS `listing` 
       WHERE `listing`.`id` = p.`listing`
       LIMIT 1 
       )
 LIMIT 1
 ) AS `listing_type_id`
```

OR use `IN` to allow multiple comparation

```
(SELECT `listing_type`.`id` 
 FROM `res_rpl_listing_types` AS `listing_type` 
 WHERE `listing_type`.`id` IN (
       SELECT `listing`.`type` 
       FROM `res_rpl_listings` AS `listing` 
       WHERE `listing`.`id` = p.`listing`)
    LIMIT 1
 ) AS `listing_type_id`
```

The problem is there is 2 subqueries and you need to treat both. Both of them need to be limited to 1 row only.

Comment: Which one? The first or seconde query?

Comment: both of them, i alredy tried both and got the same error

Comment: I have changed the answer, try again please

Comment: Great. I see you are new here. When some provided answer works, is necessary (or welcome) to accept it. It will show all other users that solution solved the problem you were having, helping everyone.